# How to correctly use PostgreSQL to limit multiple and/or concurrent executions of a task

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, redis

Let's assume you have a task `FOO` that can be queued once every minute, and a pool of 50 workers that can be paused. The queue is paused for 10 minutes, and 10 `FOO` tasks are queued. When the queue is resumed, the 10 `FOO` tasks will be executed almost concurrently (because there are more workers than tasks).

In this case, I need to ensure that no more than 1 `FOO` task per minute (time can vary) is performed.

One solution, using Redis, is to take advantage of Redis atomic and the `TTL` of a key. When a `FOO` task starts, it checks if the key `worker:FOO` exists. If does, then it exists, if it does not it sets the value and a `TTL` to the maximum frequency. This is easy to achieve using `SETNX worker:FOO whatever` and then using `TTL worker:FOO` if the previous command returned 1.

Because `SETNX` is atomic, I won't fall into the case where two `FOO` tasks are executed because of the race condition between the GET and the SET.

Now the question is: what is the correct way to achieve the same result using PostgreSQL? I can have a table with a `key` and a `executed_on` timestamp value, but how can I ensure that there is no case where two `FOO` tasks are both executed because of the delay between `FOO 1` checks the record and writes a lock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're trying to serialize work, I'd update a record in a table.

```
CREATE TABLE task_keys (
  task varchar(10) primary key,
  last_executed timestamp with time zone not null,
  by_worker_id integer
);

INSERT INTO task_keys(task, last_executed) 
VALUES ('FOO', '-infinity');
```

then to see if you can run a task yet:

```
UPDATE task_keys SET
  last_executed = current_timestamp,
  by_worker = $1
WHERE task = 'FOO'
  AND last_executed < (current_timestamp - INTERVAL '1' MINUTE)
RETURNING *;
```

The isolation rules of `READ COMMITTED` guarantee that if this query successfully updates the table and returns a row, no other query can have concurrently done so. A row lock is taken on the relevant `task_keys` row. If another `UPDATE` tries to affect the same row, it'll wait until the row lock is released by a commit or rollback of the holding transaction... then it will *re-check the `WHERE` clause*. If the other tx committed then the `WHERE` clause will no longer match, so it'll affect zero rows.

See the [documentation on transaction isolation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html).

If you need concurrency this gets a little tricker. What you really want is a token pool that refills on a timer, where workers can grab tokens from the pool to do work. That's effectively what we're doing here, with one token - so one option is to add more rows for the same task and grab the first task where the last_executed timestamp is old enough.

There are two flaws with this whole approach though:

- It doesn't know when a task *finishes*, so long running tasks could overlap; and
- It doesn't care if a task succeeds or fails

To solve those you need to use a proper work queue implementation. Those are currently very difficult to implement correctly in the database, so I suggest you look at using an external message queue / work queue system to manage them. In PostgreSQL 9.5 the new `FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED` feature will make implementing work queues like this in the database quite simple, though.

BTW, [advisory locking](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html) is often a good choice for this sort of thing, but it won't help you with the need to expire the lock automatically after a certain amount of time.

Comment: "*advisory locks won't help to expire the lock automatically*" - how would the lock obtained through an UPDATE expire automatically? If the update is never committed, it won't expire either. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The update is committed, and sets a timestamp for when the task started. So it works much like the redis approach outlined in the question. But isn't very smart about failed jobs, when jobs finish, etc; this is _not_ a proper queue system which is why I'm pointing the OP at proper queuing tools too.